# Textbox data to datagrid view

Tags: c#

i'm developing a window application which is displaying valuse in 4 textboxes 
,now i want save these textboxes data to datagrid view on save button click

like 
r1 1 1 1 1 delete

r2 2 2 2 2 delete

where delete is a button onclick of which that particular row gets deleted

Comment: Care to explaining a **tad** better?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about WPF, also question is very unclear, and is hard to understand what you're trying to do.

I think you'd better want to use A ListView if the data I/O is external (by buttons) but anyway:

Create event handlers for all the textboxes, check for existance in the DataGrid (thru DataGrid.Items), and appropriately add it to the DataGrid (again, using DataGrid.Items.Add)

To delete them use the same property to search the item you want to delete.